# Help to change the text for new website notification (wpmu_welcome_notification)

Tags: hooks, email

i am trying to change the text for new website notification (wpmu_welcome_notification):

in the core file i see wordpress using this function to send the email when new site created:

the quasion is how can i hook this function to change body text that used in "$welcome_email"

```
function wpmu_welcome_notification( $blog_id, $user_id, $password, $title, $meta = array() ) {
    $current_site = get_current_site();
    /**
     * Filter whether to bypass the welcome email after site activation.
     *
     * Returning false disables the welcome email.
     *
     * @since MU
     *
     * @param int|bool $blog_id  Blog ID.
     * @param int      $user_id  User ID.
     * @param string   $password User password.
     * @param string   $title    Site title.
     * @param array    $meta     Signup meta data.
     */
    if ( ! apply_filters( 'wpmu_welcome_notification', $blog_id, $user_id, $password, $title, $meta ) )
        return false;
    $welcome_email = get_site_option( 'welcome_email' );
    if ( $welcome_email == false )
        $welcome_email = __( 'Howdy USERNAME,
Your new SITE_NAME site has been successfully set up at:
BLOG_URL
You can log in to the administrator account with the following information:
Username: USERNAME
Password: PASSWORD
Log in here: BLOG_URLwp-login.php
We hope you enjoy your new site. Thanks!
--The Team @ SITE_NAME' );
    $url = get_blogaddress_by_id($blog_id);
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $welcome_email = str_replace( 'SITE_NAME', $current_site->site_name, $welcome_email );
    $welcome_email = str_replace( 'BLOG_TITLE', $title, $welcome_email );
    $welcome_email = str_replace( 'BLOG_URL', $url, $welcome_email );
    $welcome_email = str_replace( 'USERNAME', $user->user_login, $welcome_email );
    $welcome_email = str_replace( 'PASSWORD', $password, $welcome_email );
    /**
     * Filter the content of the welcome email after site activation.
     *
     * Content should be formatted for transmission via wp_mail().
     *
     * @since MU
     *
     * @param string $welcome_email Message body of the email.
     * @param int    $blog_id       Blog ID.
     * @param int    $user_id       User ID.
     * @param string $password      User password.
     * @param string $title         Site title.
     * @param array  $meta          Signup meta data.
     */
    $welcome_email = apply_filters( 'update_welcome_email', $welcome_email, $blog_id, $user_id, $password, $title, $meta );
    $admin_email = get_site_option( 'admin_email' );
    if ( $admin_email == '' )
        $admin_email = 'support@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $from_name = get_site_option( 'site_name' ) == '' ? 'WordPress' : esc_html( get_site_option( 'site_name' ) );
    $message_headers = "From: \"{$from_name}\" <{$admin_email}>\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"" . get_option('blog_charset') . "\"\n";
    $message = $welcome_email;
    if ( empty( $current_site->site_name ) )
        $current_site->site_name = 'WordPress';
    /**
     * Filter the subject of the welcome email after site activation.
     *
     * @since MU
     *
     * @param string $subject Subject of the email.
     */
    $subject = apply_filters( 'update_welcome_subject', sprintf( __( 'New %1$s Site: %2$s' ), $current_site->site_name, wp_unslash( $title ) ) );
    wp_mail( $user->user_email, wp_specialchars_decode( $subject ), $message, $message_headers );
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an untested example, how you could modify the email body to your needs:

```
add_filter( 'update_welcome_email', 
    function( $welcome_email, $blog_id, $user_id, $password, $title, $meta )
    {
        // Override the email body:
        $welcome_email = __( 'Dear User,

Your new SITE_NAME site has been successfully set up at:
BLOG_URL

You can log in to the administrator account with the following information:

Username: USERNAME
Password: PASSWORD
Log in here: BLOG_URLwp-login.php

We hope you enjoy your new site. Thanks!

--The Team @ SITE_NAME' );

        $current_site = get_current_site();
        $url          = get_blogaddress_by_id($blog_id);
        $user         = get_userdata( $user_id );

        return str_replace( 
            array( 'SITE_NAME', 'BLOG_TITLE', 'BLOG_URL', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD' ),
            array( $current_site->site_name, $title, $url, $user->user_login, $password ),
            $welcome_email 
        );
    }
, 10, 6 );
```

Comment: Hi @birgire, Thanks for help! but when i use this code, i get white screen and the website is not loading.

Comment: aha, it looks like there's a comma instead of a semicomma at the end ;-) @need-help